# How can I get the latest version of ConstraintLayout for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

When I try to use `ConstraintLayout` in my layout `content_main.xml`, I get the following message:

> Using version 1.0.0-alpha5 of the constraint library, which is obsolete

I am currently using the following library dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5'
```

How can I get the latest version number of constraint layout?

Comment: http://tools.android.com/recent (^F `ConstraintLayout alpha 8 is now available`)

Comment: goto this link and you can find all the recent ConstraintLayout releases 

http://tools.android.com/system/app/pages/search?scope=search-site&q=ConstraintLayout

Comment: The releases are now being listed here: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/search?q=constraint

Comment: there is a new version available : 1.1.3

Comment: i wouldn't use a reference to an alpha.  They have been known to remove those.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**EDIT:** Now that we are publishing ConstraintLayout directly on maven, you can check the maven directory:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/group-index.xml

---

Look in the SDK Manager in Android Studio. If you check the "Show Package Details" in the SDK Tools section, you should see all the available verions of ConstraintLayout (under Support Repository -> ConstraintLayout for Android)[image]

Answer (score 29):

Google finally released the official version 1.1.0 `ConstraintLayout`
So you can now import the non-beta

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

Check here for more info
http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout10isnowavailable

Comment: There's even a new version: [1.0.1](http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout101isnowavailable)

Comment: new version is `1.0.2`

Comment: Newest is ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta 1.

Comment: Thanks, Lalit, we will update it once become production

Answer (score 2):

ConstraintLayout is included on the new(ish) AndroidX releases page. Here's the direct link to see the latest versions of ConstraintLayout by track (alpha, beta, rc, stable):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout

Current view:

> [image: Screenshot of Constraintlayout releases page]

Answer (score 1):

## To Directly Pull in ConstraintLayout

Check [the Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout) for latest versions.  Use the entire version name (e.g. `2.0.0-beta2`).

### Add dependency to target module:

target_module/build.gradle

#### If using support packages:

```
android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:some-version-number`
}
```

#### If using androidx packages:

```
android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:some-version-number'
}
```

Exact Gradle lines for `2.0.0-alpha5` can be found [in the official release announcement](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout).